# Django Crispy forms doesn't save when custom layout is added

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

from views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = "employee_update.html"
    form_class = EmployeeUpdateForm
```

From forms.py:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    departments = DepartmentChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = "form-vertical"
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(Field('first_name'), css_class="row col-md-5 emp-firstname"),
            Div(Field('last_name'), css_class="row col-md-5"),
            Div(Field('title'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('email'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('phone_number'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('slack_username'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('department'), css_class="row col-md-5"),
            Div(
                Div(Field('facility_agent', template="field_checkbox_awesome.html"), css_class="row checkbox checkbox-doorman"),
                Div(Field('company_agent', template="field_checkbox_awesome.html"), css_class="row checkbox checkbox-doorman"),
                Div(Field('contact_for_company_delivery', template="field_checkbox_awesome.html"), css_class="row checkbox checkbox-doorman"),
                Div(Field('contact_for_facility_delivery', template="field_checkbox_awesome.html"), css_class="row checkbox checkbox-doorman"),
                css_class="row col-md-5 emp-department"),
            Div(Field('mugshot'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('company'), css_class="row col-md-10"),
            Div(Field('facility'), css_class="row col-md-10")
        )
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "first name"
        self.fields['last_name'].label = "last name"
        self.fields['title'].label = "title"
        self.fields['email'].label = "email"
        self.fields['phone_number'].label = "phone #"
        self.fields['slack_username'].label = "slack name"
        self.fields['facility_agent'].label = "facility agent"
        self.fields['company_agent'].label = "company agent"
        self.fields['contact_for_company_delivery'].label = "contact for company delivery"
        self.fields['contact_for_facility_delivery'].label = "contact for facility delivery"

    class Meta:
        model = Employee


class EmployeeCreateForm(EmployeeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class EmployeeUpdateForm(EmployeeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        employee = Employee.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.pk).first()
        self.fields['departments'].set_company(employee.department_id)
```

and urls.py:

```
url(r'employees/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', EmployeeUpdateView.as_view(), name="employee_update"),
```

If I comment out the "form_class = " line in views.py, the edits are saved.  If I put it in, the edits are not.
The fields are definitely sent up via the POST and there are no errors being logged on the console.

Comment: Do you see that in ```views.py``` you have ```EmployeeUpdateForm```, when in ```forms.py``` there is ```EmployeeForm```?

Comment: Yes...scroll down.  EmployeeUpdateForm subclasses EmployeeForm.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. I recommend you to replace ```employee = Employee.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.pk).first()``` with ```employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=self.instance.pk)```, because using ```..filter(...).first()``` can suppress error, which shouldn't be suppressed.

Comment: Good point...changed it.  Makes no difference for saving though..still doesn't :-(

Comment: What is `self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)` for? I'm not sure but might that be messing with your request object unnecessarily?

Try putting a `form_valid` method in your form model and seeing what the validated form looks like. Do the same with the `save` method of your model to see why it isn't saving.

Comment: Commented out the pop request and made no difference.  Weird part is I put this in EmployeeUpdateView and it never gets called:     def form_valid(self, form):
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)  
        self.object.save()
        return super(EmployeeUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

Comment: added this to the Employee model and it never gets called:     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "employee is " + self
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `form_valid` isn't getting called, it means that the issue isn't that your form isn't saving, it's that the data you're passing to the form isn't passing validation. [Take a look here at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views).

To debug the issue, start by putting a `form_invalid()` method in your view or a [custom `clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/) in your form, and see why the form isn't validating. I.e., check out the errors in the form instance and see what that shows you. That should answer your question.

There are also some methods you're calling that may or may not be making the form invalid before it's even instantiated. I'm not sure what the `set_company` method does on a field but it may have an error whereby your form isn't getting setup properly.

Comment: Didn't realize form_invalid was still called for crispy forms.  I added a method for it and a breakpoint and did "p form.errors" and it showed the field I added temporarily (Departments) and forgot about was marked as required but I didn't show it in the form :-P